# Assign anonymous function to onchange

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = (function() {   
    alert(select.options[0].value);
})();
```

I'm trying to make this work but no luck. I want this anonymous function to fire on load then should work on change event. Can anyone explain me why it is not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnybn/2/

Comment: As noted in the answers, you're executing the function, and it doesn't look like you should be doing that. In some cases, an IIFE can be useful, but then you'd have to return a function reference, and with alert you could do that like so -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lnybn/3/**

Comment: To trigger onload, add `select.onchange()` on the line below the event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you both define a function AND call it immediately after, assigning its result to `onchange`. Just drop the parens to assign a function instead:

```
select.onchange = function() {   
    alert(select.options[0].value);
};
```

If you want to trigger this function immediately after, wrap the whole expression in parens, then call it:

```
(select.onchange = function() {   
    alert(select.options[0].value);
})();
```

... as the result of assignment operation is the value assigned, which, in this case, is a function.

Comment: I think OP wants to fire the `onchange` event on onload by calling anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line:

```
document.onload = select.onchange();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnybn/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the function and invoke it at the same time. It doesn't make any sense. First assign it:

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = function() {   
    alert(select.options[0].value);
};
```

Actually you're JSFiddle example is fine here. ;-)

Then if you want to invoke it on page load, just do it, but after you assign it;

```
select.onchange();
```